# Why shouldn't I make my custom struct with sequence object?

Tags: swift, generics

I want my struct to be created with sequence object using type inference. like:

```
var words: Buffer = ["generics", "ftw"] // type should be Buffer<String>
```

so I created a struct like this

```
struct Buffer<Element> {
init<S>(_ s: S) where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence {
}}
```

I just wrote code like above for testing generic init.

the code works when I create a struct like this:

```
var words = Buffer(["generics", "ftw"])
```

but I can't create a struct like this:

```
var words: Buffer = ["generics", "ftw"]
```

or

```
var words: Buffer<String> = ["generics", "ftw"]
```

the compiler complains me:

> contextual type 'Buffer' cannot be used with array literal

I think I gave enough information to compiler as:

hey compiler, you'll gonna receive a Sequence. and the Element I mentioned is Sequence's Element.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the syntax sugar, you have to adopt the [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) protocol, which will make your `struct` able to be initialized using an array literal.

```
extension Buffer: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    typealias ArrayLiteralElement = Element

    init(arrayLiteral: Element...) {
        self.init(arrayLiteral)
    }
}
```

After adding this extension, code like

```
var words: Buffer = ["generics", "ftw"]
```

or

```
var words: Buffer<String> = ["generics", "ftw"]
```

will compile.

Note that this does *not* mean that `words` is an array, although it is initialized with an array literal. If you assign the words variable to a variable that is of the `Array` type, your code will not compile, and vice versa. Also, note that if you don't infer the type `Buffer` in the variable declaration, it will be inferred as `Array`, so you *must* include `Buffer` in the variable decleration.

Comment: Note that this helps only with array *literals.* `let a = ["generics", "few"] ; var words: Buffer = a` would not compile.

Comment: @MartinR added a note about that